Microphone getting muted and active continuously in ubuntu-24.04-desktop
I'm new to Ubuntu. I recently Installed ubuntu-24.04-desktop on my Lenovo ideapad 330 (81DE). Now the internal microphone getting muted and active continuously and this notification appearing on the screen with "beep" alert.
This is very annoying. Please give me solution for this issue.
Thank you.
